# How to track each time a new setInterval on an array of elements arriving from the API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

1. I receive data from the API, and I save only objects with status 1 or 2 to the state.

`const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

```
      const handleOnFetchData = useCallback((data) => {
        setItems(
          data.results.filter(
            (report) => report.status === 1 || report.status === 2
          )
        );
      }, []);`
```

2. Objects change their status over time. And you need to track it every 5 seconds in the interval.

How I do:

1. There is a useEffect that depends on the state with items, and if the state is not empty, then iterates over the state and calls the monitoringItem function for each element

`let interval;

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (items.length > 0) {
      items.forEach((report, i) => {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
          monitoringItem(report.record_id);
        }, 5000);
      });
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [items]);`
```

2. the monitoringItem function sends a request every 5 seconds and checks the status of the item. if the status is anything other than 1 or 2, then stop the interval and remove that item from the state.

   ```
   const monitoringItem = useCallback(
         async (id) => {
           const response = await API.get(`/reports/${id}`);

           const monitoredReport = response.data.results[0];

           if (monitoredReport.status !== 2 && monitoredReport.status !== 1) {
             clearInterval(interval);
             setItems(
               items.filter((rep) => rep.record_id !== monitoredReport.record_id)
             );
           }
         },
         [items]
       );
   ```

**Question and problem**: How can I hang my own setInterval for each item when adding. Now everything is fine with 1 item. but adding others breaks everything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You only have one variable `interval` but you are setting potentially many intervals in that forEach.  Perhaps you could move the forEach inside of the setInterval.

Comment: @Community I need to make a queue of api requests every 5 seconds if the object has a certain status.

Comment: And I need to check that the interval is already running